# Why does my program act as though it doesn't find images on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, algorithm

I already have a gallery thats load the images building elements with javascript, is something like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#getElement").click(function() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            var ancla = document.createElement("A");
            var img = document.createElement("IMG");
            var text = document.createTextNode("");
            img.src = 'images/tile' + i + '.jpg';
            img.id = "image";
            img.appendChild(text);
            ancla.href = 'images/tile' + i + '.jpg';
            ancla.className = "boxing";
            ancla.appendChild(text);
            document.getElementById("gallery").appendChild(ancla);
            ancla.appendChild(img);
            loadimage('images/tile' + i + '.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

i want to put a condition that load the images of the gallery just if they exist in the server or wherever they are stored. For that i declare a global variable named "warning" in my script, i use that variable inside the function that load every image of the gallery, the variable is boolean and become true if at least one image is found and false if no image where found. Here is that function:

```
var req, image, imagepath;
var warning = false;

function d(o) {
    return document.getElementById(o);
}

function loadimage(imgpath) {
    image = d("image");
    image.style.display = "none";
    imagepath = imgpath;
    req = getreq();
    req.onreadystatechange = imagexists;
    req.open("get", imagepath, true);
    req.send(null);
}

function imagexists() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            warning = true;
            image.style.display = "block";
            image.src = imagepath;
        } else {
            image.style.display = "none";
            warning = false;
        }
    }
}

function getreq() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

after the for sentence of the click function i put the code for the condition

```
if (warning == true) {
    $("#gallery").justifiedGallery({
        filter: false,
        rowHeight: 180
    });
} else {
    $("#dynamicCont").load('noImage.txt');
}
```

this is where the code doesn't work like it should because its always enter in the else of the condition even if the function loadimage() found an image. Is there anything that im missing? or another ways to make this work properly?

Comment: Are you appending text to the img element? It is wrong. You cannot add any children to the img element

Comment: *"the variable is boolean and become true if at least one image is found and false if no image where found"* In that case, you've got `warning = true` and `warning = false` reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what's happening is that this code:

```
if (warning == true) {
    $("#gallery").justifiedGallery({
        filter: false,
        rowHeight: 180
    });
} else {
    $("#dynamicCont").load('noImage.txt');
}
```

Is running before your request to the server has completed. Remember that this is an asynchronous request.

Just move that code to your callback function like so:

```
function imagexists() {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
      image.style.display = "block";
      image.src = imagepath;

      $("#gallery").justifiedGallery({
        filter: false,
        rowHeight: 180
      });

    } else {
      image.style.display = "none";
      $("#dynamicCont").load('noImage.txt');
    }
  }
}
```

You don't really need the warning boolean this way.

Comment: i try what you say and it work well, just that now i dont know why the content called with $("#dynamicCont").load('noImage.txt'); is not called when there's no images in the gallery.

Comment: Hard to say. If you step into the code using your debugger do you see it get into the `$("#dynamicCont").load('noImage.txt');` line?

Comment: Is working fine now, the condition to enter in the $("#dynamicCont").load('noImage.txt'); line was an empty request, it means a req.status = 404

Comment: Ok great. I thought the `else` would have caught the 404 or any other response code, but as long as it's working :)